# Open source library to plot graphs for functions in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, math, graph

I am looking for some library using which I can plot graphs by giving it a function equation like:

- sin(x)
- x^2+sin(x)

If not this, then I can give (x,y) values for currently visible range and that library should plot this in a view. If anyone knows any such library then please tell.

Comment: 1) This question is off-topic. 2) Did you even attempt any sort of search for iOS graphing libraries? Google is quite useful for that.

Comment: Yes I tried core-plot but it does not seem to be much useful for my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Plot can plot function data easily. It includes a helper class (`CPTFunctionDataSource`) that makes it easy to plot calculated data from a c-function or Objective-C block. See the "Math Function Plot" demo in the *Plot Gallery* example app for sample code. It plots `y = sin(x)` as a demo.

Comment: Hello, is there a CPTFunctionDataSource demo app on Swift?

Comment: No, but it should work. Use the block form (e.g., create the datasource with `+dataSourceForPlot:withBlock:`). The block takes a `double` input parameter and returns a `double` value.